# how to divide two intengers and get a result with decimal numbers?

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, decimal, contiki

I'm doing a project in Contiki to a Zolertia module where I need to calculate the risk of a wildfire to occur.

To calculate this risk the formula used is `Risk = Temperature / Humidity`.
The result of **Risk** it's a decimal value and there are 5 different values range to classify this Risk: `0-0.49 , 0.5-0.99, 1-1.49, 1.5-1.99, >=2`.

My problem is that I can't get decimal results. When I run it in the terminal it shows the value of Temperature and the value of Humidity but just a blank space in the value of Risk.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "contiki.h"
#include <float.h>

PROCESS(temp_hum_fog, "Wildfire Control");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&temp_hum_fog);

static struct etimer et;

PROCESS_THREAD(temp_hum_fog, ev, data)
{
    
    int16_t temp, hum;
    float risk;

    PROCESS_BEGIN()


    while(1) {
        etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND);
        PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));

        temp = rand() % 45;
        hum = rand() % (85-5)+5;
        risk = (float)temp/(float)hum;

        printf("Temperature:%d ºC\nHumidity:%d HR\nRisk:%f\n", temp,hum,risk);

    }

    PROCESS_END();


}
```

If I change the type of `temp` and `hum` to `float` it won't show any results also so I'm not sure if `float` works in Contiki.

Does someone know any solution?

Comment: Contiki is an OS, not a language.  What's the language?  If it's C or C++ as it appears, how is `risk` declared?  And is your library documented as supporting floating point for `printf`?

Comment: @NateEldredge The language is C. I updated the Question with the full code.

Comment: @JoãoSacramento when you change the type of `temp` and `hum` to float did you also change the format specifier in `printf` to `%f`?

Comment: I tested your code on my machine (after getting rid of the OS-specific etimer and PROCESS stuff) and it printed `Temperature:22 ºC
Humidity:54 HR
Risk:0.407407
`.  Which looks fine.  So it's likely there's something wrong with the floating-point support in your environment.

Comment: The answer to your question, "how to divide two intengers and get a result with decimal numbers?", is to use something like `risk = (float)temp/(float)hum`, that is, exactly what you have.  You're doing the right thing.  It ought to work.

Comment: Does the C implementation you are using support floating-point output in `printf`? What does `printf("%f\n", 3.5f);` print?

Comment: @phuclv yes I did.

Comment: @SteveSummit is there anything I can do?

Comment: @EricPostpischil it shows a blank space.

Comment: @JoãoSacramento Based on the result of Eric's experiment, it sounds very much like your version of `printf` does *not* support floating-point.  There may be some platform-specific way of enabling floating-point support, but i know nothing about Contiki so I cant help with that.  What you can do is a by-hand fixed-point division, as Eric has already demonstrated in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C implementation you are using is not a full standard C implementation and does not support floating-point conversions in `printf`. Three options are:

- Check the documentation for your C implementation to see if support for floating-point can be enabled.
- Find another C implementation to use (particularly the standard C library).
- Use integer arithmetic, as in the example below, to do calculations.

This code will print the quotient to two decimal places, rounded down, using only integer arithmetic:

```
    int integer  = temp/hum;
    int fraction = temp%hum * 100 / hum;
    printf("Risk: %d.%02d\n", integer, fraction);
```

Note this assumes the values involved are positive; negative numbers could cause undesired outputs.

Comment: This is the best option. There's no support for floating-point output for printf and I couldn't find any solution for it. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I have a few suggestions:

1. Specify the literals with either a trailing 'f' or add a decimal place in

`temp = rand() % 45; hum = rand() % (85-5)+5;`

2. Declare temp and hum as floats and then cast the result of rand()